# Resetting Center of Map in Google Maps through Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have an MVC application that is using Google Maps throughout the app.  To make things simple, I've created a JavaScript file that initializes the map and sets the map display.

In my application, I want to allow a front end developer to change the center of the map location with a simple JavaScript call.  Unfortunately, after declaring the map and loading the application, if you try to make a JavaScript call back to the map variable, the map JS variable (and all variables) are null.  This drops the instance to the map, and does not let me change the location (I believe).

In the JS Code below, I'm trying to call setLocation from the HTML page to reset the location.  This is the fail part of the code.  Help is appreciated.

```
var map;
var geocoder;
var marker;

$(document).ready(function () {
    initialize();
    $(function () {
        $("#address").autocomplete({
            //This bit uses the geocoder to fetch address values
            source: function (request, response) {
                geocoder.geocode({ 'address': request.term }, function (results, status) {
                    response($.map(results, function (item) {
                        return {
                            label: item.formatted_address,
                            value: item.formatted_address,
                            latitude: item.geometry.location.lat(),
                            longitude: item.geometry.location.lng()
                        }
                    }));
                })
            },

            select: function (event, ui) {
                $("#Place_Latitude").val(ui.item.latitude);
                $("#Place_Longitude").val(ui.item.longitude);
                var location = new google.maps.LatLng(ui.item.latitude, ui.item.longitude);
                marker.setPosition(location);
                map.setCenter(location);
            }
        });
    });
});

function setLocation(lat, lon) {
    var location = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lon);
    marker.setPosition(location);
    map.setCenter(location);
}
function initialize() {
    var location = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
    var mapOptions = {
        center: location, zoom: 8, mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        draggable: true
    });
    marker.setPosition(location);

    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
}
```

Comment: have you tried removing the var map; line?  Seems like you are setting up a new var called map, instead of referencing the one you setup previously.

Answer (score 0):

This looks bad:

```
return {
       label: item.formatted_address,
       value: item.formatted_address,
       latitude: item.geometry.location.lat(),
       longitude: item.geometry.location.lng()
       }
```

The geocoder is asynchronous and can't return anything from the callback routine.  you need to use the variables inside the callback.

Answer (score 0):

There is an example of what you are trying to do [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/events#EventArguments)...

Have a look at theie [placeMarker](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/events#EventArguments) function and how they have initialized the map...

My suggestion would be to start with this example and make sure that works. If so, it should be relatively straight forward to determine what is different in your implementation.